# How to filter this output from powershell?

Tags: command-line, powershell

This is my powershell command: `powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -Command  "(gwmi win32_process | select ProcessID,ParentProcessID,@{e={$_.GetOwner().User}}, CommandLine) | ft -AutoSize"`

When I run it I get the following output

```
C:\Users\Administrator>powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -Command  "(gwmi win32_process | select ProcessID,ParentProcessID,@{e={$_.GetOwner().User}}, CommandLine) | ft -AutoSize"

ProcessID ParentProcessID $_.GetOwner().User CommandLine
--------- --------------- ------------------ -----------
        0               0
        4               0
      236               4 SYSTEM
      332             320 SYSTEM
      384             320 SYSTEM             wininit.exe
      392             376 SYSTEM
      420             376 SYSTEM             winlogon.exe
      476             384 SYSTEM
      484             384 SYSTEM             C:\Windows\system32\lsass.exe
      544             476 SYSTEM             C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k DcomLaunch
      584             476 NETWORK SERVICE    C:\Windows\system32\svchost.exe -k RPCSS
      680             420 DWM-1              "dwm.exe"
...
     1256            1176 Administrator      "C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe" -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -
     3052            3000 Administrator      \??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe 0x4
     2760            2856 Administrator      "C:\cygwin64\bin\bash.exe"
     2104            1176 Administrator      "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe"
     1504            2104 Administrator      \??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe 0x4
     2440            1108 Administrator      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
     1268            2440 Administrator      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=gpu-process --channel="2440.0.15...
     2472            2440 Administrator      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer --enable-deferred-image...
     1496            2440 Administrator      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --type=renderer --enable-deferred-image...
     2640            2840 user001             C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c c:\windows\temp\tmpyaoyv0.bat
     1040            2640 user001             \??\C:\Windows\system32\conhost.exe 0x4
```

I want to be able to filter for the `user001` process

If I use **where-object**, I got this error:

```
+ ...  where-object {$.e -eq user001} | ft -AutoSize
+                    ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: ($.e:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If I use **where**, I got this:

```
}}, CommandLine) | where $_.GetOwner().User -eq 'user001' | ft -AutoSize"
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ (gwmi win32_process | select ProcessID,ParentProcessID,@{e={$_.GetOwner().User}} ..
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

So what is the proper way to filter on `$_.GetOwner().User`?

Comment: Did you mean `$_`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3494115/what-does-mean-in-powershell

Comment: It does not help me at all. I know `$_` means this. How can I access the user information from `$_`? Do I suppose to use where or where-object?

Comment: If you know that $_ means that, then why are you trying to use `$.e` in your code?  You need to look at your errors output again.

Answer (score 0):

Your error are just a standard syntax error you got by not using the `$_`.  If you do use the propper `$_.attribute` you will get another error because of your unquoted use of `user001`.

Ignoring the syntax errors what you probably need is to do is set a name for the value in the Select-Object expression.  This way you can easily use it later.

```
(gwmi win32_process | `
 Select-Object ProcessID, ParentProcessID, `
               @{Name='Owner';
                Expression={$_.GetOwner().User}}, `
               CommandLine) | `
Where-Object {$_.Owner -eq 'user001'}
```

Comment: it does not work: powershell -noprofile -NonInteractive -Command '(gwmi win32_process | Select-Object ProcessID, ParentProcessID, @{Name="Owner";
 Expression={$_.GetOwner().User}}, CommandLine) | Where-Object {$_.Owner -eq "dop001"} | ft -AutoSize '   Error message:'Select-Object' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.